How can I avoid Messing up my UV map when I use edge slide *Correct face attributes doesn't work on me
I'm currently reducing the polycount of my mesh. I'm using edge slide because it's easier and it will mirror to the other side, but I found out that Edge Slide messes the UV map, I found some answers saying that you should turn on Correct Face Attributes, but it doesn't work on me is there a way to avoid this issue?
This image shows that I turn on the Correct Face Attributes function

This is where I perform the edge slide and It also shows that the one of the vertices in the UV split in two


when you slide (GG), in the Operator Box there is an option called Correct UVs that should be activated, is it the case? It should keep the UV about good, if it's not the case I guess you need to unwrap correctly again

The Edge Slide operator has an option to Correct UVs which should be enabled by default. I've tested on version 4.2 to 3.4.1, and it seems to be working fine. What's the Blender version you're using? Can you confirm that Edge Slide has the Correct UVs option on your side? I am guessing that the issue is with Auto Merge. Try preforming an Edge Slide with it disabled.

Good morning @Mr A Thank you for answering currently the blender version I'm using is 3.6.9 but I also have the 4.2.3 to try if it will work.
If you are talking about the correct face attributes settings in blender, I already use that function but it still doing it. It's in the image but I'm not sure if that's what you are saying.

Good morning @moonboots Thank you for the answer where can I see that Correct UVs function in blender? I'm thinking it's not the correct face attributes that I'm using. Please correct me if I'm wrong

it's in the Operator Box, but it should be enabled by default: https://i.postimg.cc/PrCm4mbk/1.jpg
